# PDO Fetch, Execute, statements etc

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I've been reading books and many posts regarding proper and recommended methods to retrieve and insert data OOP way.

I cant fully understand the "query, select, fetch, execute" commands, where and when to use them. Don't get me wrong, I've been trying to read them from other peoples examples and stuff but I need a simple example to help me understand the logic of them.

If you have any short and on the point examples of these methods, used in a real situation please post it, I would very much appreciate it!!

I coded something even tho all to me is a bit blur because I actually started with advanced stuff but I need an explanation for the above commands to help me understand and get started.

```
<?php 
   class DB { 

      private    $_pdo, 
           $_query,  
           $_error = false,  
           $_results,  
           $_count = 0; 

      private function __construct() { 
               try { 
                  $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password')); 
                    } catch(PDOException $e) { 
                  die($e->getMessage()); 
                       }             
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple, the flow is the same for all most any database driver:

1. You first create a connection (`new PDO(...)`)
2. Once you have a connection you can prepare the query `prepare()`
3. calling `prepare()` will return a `statement` object if successfull
4. using the `statement object` you can execute the query.
5. If the query returns result you will need to `fetch()` the rows, in order to read the values.

---

```
#see corresponding bullet
try { 
    $this->_pdo = new PDO('....');           #1
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';
    $statement = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql); #2|#3
    $statment->execute();                    #4
    $row = $statement->fetch();              #5
    //var_dump($row);
} catch(PDOException $e) { 
    die($e->getMessage()); 
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, thanks for the logic. If you don't mind, could you make up a single example with all these ?

Comment: @Flowx I expanded on my answer

Comment: Thank you very much, meda! Appreciate it

Comment: welcome bro, and read the manual in addition to articles and books